# How can I delete a node from a singly linked list?

Tags: c#

I'm taking lines (I:3, I:6, D:5, etc) from a text file and splitting them on the colon. Then, taking the number after the colon and pushing it to a node in a linked list. Depending on the line, it will insert(I) or delete(D) the node. However, I'm having trouble deleting a node. I created a method called deleteNode()

I reference this method in my if statement to check whether or not the command in the file starts with I or D to be told whether it gets inserted or deleted or not. I'm having trouble on how to reference the node to be deleted in llist.deletenode();

```
public class LinkedList
{
    Node head; // the head of list

    public class Node
    {
        public int data;
        public Node next;

        // constructor
        public Node(int d)
        {
            data = d;
            next = null;
        } // end of constructor
    }

    public void printList()
    {
        // traversing list and printing the contents starting from head(1)
        Node n = head;
        int count = 0;

        while (n != null)
        {
            count++;
            Console.Write("Node" + count + ":" + " " + n.data + " ");
            n = n.next;
        }
    }

    public void push(int new_data)
    {
        // ads node to list
        Node new_node = new Node(new_data); //allocate new node, put in data
        new_node.next = head; //make next of new node as head
        head = new_node; //moving head to point to the new node
    }

    public static void deleteNode(Node node, Node n)
    {
        // deletes node from list
        // find the previous node 
        Node prev = node;

        while (prev.next != null && prev.next != n)
        {
            prev = prev.next;
        }

        // Check if node really exists in Linked List 
        if (prev.next == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Given node is not" +
                              "present in Linked List");
            return;
        }

        // Remove node from Linked List 
        prev.next = prev.next.next;
        // Free memory 
        GC.Collect();
        return;
    }
}

// main method to create a linked list with 3 nodes
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    // starting with an empty list
    LinkedList llist = new LinkedList();
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\Users\project\text.txt");

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        // splitting the lines on the colon
        string[] bits = line.Split(':');

        // taking the bit after the colon and parsing 
        // into an integer - the i is already parsed
        int x = int.Parse(bits[1]); //the value after colon

        if (bits[0] == "i")
        {
            llist.push(x);
        }
        else if (bits[0] == "d")
        {
            deleteNode(llist, existingNode); //error here
        }

    }

    llist.printList();
}
```

Comment: Aside: It seems a little peculiar that you check `bits[0]` for `"i"` to insert, but look elsewhere, `bits[1]`, for `"d"` to delete.

Comment: All you know about the node you want to delete is its value (PS it would help if you had posted `Node`s definition) so your `deleteNode` must take in a value as its second argument (`int`) and then your loop must check if the next node's value equals the deletion value.

Comment: I think your current logic is going to have an issue with deleting the first node of any linked list. You would either need to pass the node variable as a `ref`, or instead return the first node of your modified linked list from the delete function so that you can create a new node to act as a dummy header should it be the first node in the list that requires deletion.

Comment: `@"C:\\Users\text.txt"` has 1 `\\` too many.

Comment: In your example, it looks like you `Insert(3)`, then `Insert(6)`, then `Delete(5)`. Since `5` has not been inserted, what is the expected output?

Comment: Please do not vandalise questions, even if they are your own questions. The purpose of Stack Overflow is to be a repository of questions and answers which can help everyone, not just the person who asked the original question.

Comment: Make `deleteNode()` a class method and call it using `llist.deleteNode(existingNode);`

Answer (score 0):

DeleteNode method takes in two arguments. You are using deleteNode as an extension method but it's a simple method with two inputs.

```
deleteNode(llist, nodeYouWantToDelete);
```

Also, your loop that checks for D isn't right

```
if (bits[0] == "i") { //loop that checks if command starts with i (for inserting)
    llist.push(x);
    } else if(bits[0] == "d") { // CHECK bits[0] not [1]
       // Get the node that matches value
       // check here if the node already exists then delete
        deleteNode(llist, existingNode);    
    }
```

**update**

```
public void push(int new_data) { //ads node to list

    Node new_node = new Node(new_data); //allocate new node, put in data

    new_node.next = null;   //next should always be null.
    // start from head and find the node whose next = null, point that to new_node

}

public void deleteNode(Node nodeToDelete) {   //deletes node from list
     // start from head and keep going next until node.next =  nodeToDelete
   // set node.next = node.next.next;
}
```

---

**Working Solution for you**

```
public class LinkedList
{
    Node head;
    Node last;

    public class Node
    {
        public int data;
        public Node next;

        public Node(int d)
        {
            data = d;
            next = null;
        } // end of constructor
    }
    public void print()
    {
        // traversing list and printing the contents starting from head(1)
        Node n = head;
        int count = 0;

        while (n != null)
        {
            Console.Write("Node" + count++ + ":" + " " + n.data + " ");
            n = n.next;
        }
    }
    public void push(int new_data)
    {
        Node thisNode = new Node(new_data);

        if (head == null)
        {
            head = thisNode;
            last = head;
            return;
        }
        last.next = thisNode;
        last = last.next;
    }
    public void delete(Node node)
    {
        if (head.data == node.data)
            head = head.next;

        else
        {

            Node iterate = head;
            bool deleted = false;
            while (iterate.next != null)
            {
                if (iterate.next.data == node.data && !deleted)
                {
                    iterate.next = iterate.next.next;
                    deleted = true;
                    continue;
                }

                iterate.next = iterate.next.next;
            }
            last = iterate;

            if (!deleted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Given node is not " +
                                    "present in Linked List");
            }

            // Free memory 
            GC.Collect();
            return;
        }
    }
}

//and use it in the main like,

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    LinkedList llist = new LinkedList();
    string[] lines = new[] { "i:1", "i:3", "d:3", "i:2", "i:1", "d:3" };

    foreach(string line in lines)
    {
        string[] split = line.Split(':');
        if (split[0] == "i")      // INSERTS At the end of the list.
            llist.push(int.Parse(split[1]));

        else if (split[0] == "d") // Deletes the "FIRST" occurence of said number
            llist.delete(new LinkedList.Node(int.Parse(split[1])));
    }

    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: You will have to make your method static if you are calling from the static Main method, `public static void deleteNode(...`

Comment: Well, that helps.. to see how the code looks and all. You dont need to use static since it's part of the LinkedList class. Remove static modifier from that deleteNode. I'll update the code to show how it should be used.

Comment: @Matthew see the updated post. Includes a full working solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the logic should probably match that of the `push` method (not sure why `push` isn't called `Add` or `Insert` instead, though...), in that it should look for the first node whose data matches the data we want to delete.

If we start at the head, we first want to determine if the head should be deleted. If so, then we reset the head to `head.next` and we're done!

Otherwise, we examine `head.Next` to see if it's the one to delete. If it is, then we set `head.Next` equal to `head.Next.Next`, effectively removing `head.Next` from our list (no node is pointing to it anymore).

If `head.Next` is **not** the node to delete, then we move to the next node and continue the process.

Here's an example:

```
public void DeleteNode(int nodeData)
{
    // First check if the head is the node to delete
    if (head != null && head.data == nodeData)
    {
        // If it is, set the head to the next node (effectively removing it from the list)
        head = head.next;
        return;
    }

    // Start at the head node
    var current = head;

    while (current != null)
    {
        // Get the next node
        var next = current.next;

        // See if the next node is the one to delte
        if (next != null && next.data == nodeData)
        {
            // It is, so set the current node's Next pointer to the *next* node's 
            // Next pointer (effectively removing the Next node from the list)
            current.next = next.next;
            return;
        }

        // Update our current node to the next one and keep looking
        current = next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues with your code ranging from aesthetic (name casing), to syntax errors, to design errors (static functions instead of methods).

I am offering some cleanup and an example below. The result is

```
Print List:
Node1: 0 Node2: 1 Node3: 2 Node4: 3 Node5: 4 Node6: 5

Deleting 4
Print List:
Node1: 0 Node2: 1 Node3: 2 Node4: 3 Node5: 5
```

and the sample code. The main addition is a separate function that finds the previous node `FindPrevious()` and use the existing `Head` of the list in `DeleteNode()`.

Also changed fields into properties and PascalCasing as recommended per C# design rules.

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Node
    {
        public int Data { get; set; }
        public Node Next { get; set; }

        // constructor
        public Node(int data)
            : this(null, data)
        { }
        // always add a full constructor
        public Node(Node next, int data)
        {
            this.Data = data;
            this.Next = next;
        }
    }

    public class LinkedList
    {
        public Node Head { get; set; }

        public string PrintList()
        {
            // traversing list and printing the contents starting from head(1)
            Node n = Head;
            int count = 0;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while (n != null)
            {
                count++;
                sb.Append("Node" + count + ":" + " " + n.Data + " ");
                n = n.Next;
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        // adds node to list
        public void Push(int data)
        {

            //allocate new node, put in data
            //and make next of new node as head
            //moving head to point to the new node
            Head = new Node(Head, data); 
        }

        public Node FindPrevious(Node node)
        {
            Node n = Head;
            while (n!=null)
            {
                if (n.Next == node)
                {
                    return n;
                }
                n = n.Next;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void DeleteNode(Node node)
        {
            if (node==null)
            {
                return;
            }
            Node prev = FindPrevious(node);
            if (prev!=null)
            {
                // skip over node
                prev.Next = node.Next;
            }
        }
    }
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LinkedList llist = new LinkedList();

            llist.Push(5);
            llist.Push(4);
            llist.Push(3);
            llist.Push(2);
            llist.Push(1);
            llist.Push(0);

            Console.WriteLine($"Print List:");
            Console.WriteLine(llist.PrintList());
            Console.WriteLine();
            var existingNode = llist.Head.Next.Next.Next.Next;
            Console.WriteLine($"Deleting {existingNode.Data}");
            llist.DeleteNode(existingNode);
            Console.WriteLine($"Print List:");
            Console.WriteLine(llist.PrintList());
        }
    }
}
```